# PHP setlocale and strftime broken characters? (nb_NO)

Tags: php, internationalization, locale

I am trying to display a date in Norwegian with strftime like so:

`echo strftime('%a,%e.%m.', $timestamp);`

However, for a date such as `Sunday, February 6` which above should be formatted as `Lø,02.6` returns as `L�., 6.02.` When trying to display the full day with `%A`, it renders as `L�rdag`.

(I'm not sure if this character is only displaying wrongly for me on a mac, but [here is a screenshot](http://d.pr/i/1bSSX/1AzUWMVe) in case)

In the head of my HTML, I have set `<meta charset="UTF-8">` and via PHP, it is set via `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nb_NO');`

**edit**
Even going directly into the php console on the server with `php -a` and executing:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nb_NO');
echo strftime('%a','20160206');
```

I get `l�.`

Comment: What system are you running? If it's Linux, open your console and run `locale -a` and see if you have `nb_NO.UTF8` installed.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting, especially after the direct console tests in the edit, I ran a `locale -a` and noticed that the UTF-8 locale was not installed via my original `sudo locale-gen nb_NO`, so I ran:

`sudo locale-gen nb_NO.utf8` and then also had to set the locale accordingly `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nb_NO.utf8');` and everything is working well now.